# Camunda won't recover from lost database connection

Tags: camunda

When the database connection breaks down during job execution, the Camunda process-engine fails to recover from it (i.e. it never seems to reconnect once the database server is available again).

The following exception is being thrown again and again:

> 2019-10-24 16:04:59.955 5bb01d51 error org.camunda.bpm.engine.context ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: ; ### Error querying database. Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket; ### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml; ### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute-Inline; ### The error occurred while setting parameters; ### SQL: select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( select RES.* from ACT_RU_JOB RES where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0) and (RES.DUEDATE_ is null or RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?) and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?) and RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1 and ( ( RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1 and not exists( select J2.* from ACT_RU_JOB J2 where J2.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ -- from the same proc. inst. and (J2.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1) -- also exclusive and (J2.LOCK_OWNER_ is not null and J2.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ >= ?) -- in progress ) ) or RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 0 ) ) a where ROWNUM < ?) where rnum >= ?; ### Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket process-engine BaseLogger.java:156
>   ...

Has anybody had this happen before, and if you were able to fix it, could you explain how?

I also filed a Camunda bug ticket (https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-11465), but at Camunda they think this is either a configuration issue or an application error on our side, which we are not so certain about.

They asked for more information, but this is pretty much all there is: Camunda runs, the database connection gets lost, then is available again, but Camunda never reconnects. I don't see how this can possible be a database or application issue.

We did update to the latest Camunda version (7.12.0). The issue seems to be independent of the database driver as our customer runs OracleDB while in the Camunda bug ticket somebody mentioned having the same issue with PostgreSQL.